# Webdriver.IO receiving: "npm ERR! Test failed. See above for more details." but can't see the errors

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io

I've created a simple test which verify that the appearance number of breadcrumbs in a specific site is 2:

The site is: https://theculturetrip.com/europe/united-kingdom/england/london/before-you-go/

The 2 breadcrumbs (in blue circle):
[breadcrumbs_screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zq4NM.png)

**My test:** ('[itemprop="item"]' is the breadcrumbs button CSS selector)

```
it.only('Upper display shows the breadcrumbs', function () {
    let breadcrumbsAppearancesNumber = $$('[itemprop="item"]').length;
    expect(breadcrumbsAppearancesNumber).to.equal(2);
});
```

And for 2 it works well.

However, just for testing purpose when I insert 3:

```
it.only('Upper display shows the breadcrumbs', function () {
    let breadcrumbsAppearancesNumber = $$('[itemprop="item"]').length;
    expect(breadcrumbsAppearancesNumber).to.equal(3);
});
```

It obviously fails, with the output: "npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details."

However when I scrolling above I don't see any error messages that can give me extra information on why it fails...

It shows:

```
Stdout:

2019-01-06T11:35:15.971Z INFO wdio-cli:Launcher: Run onPrepare hook

2019-01-06T11:35:19.200Z INFO wdio-local-runner: Start worker 0-0 with arg: --spec=tests/InnerArticleTest.js

[0-0] 2019-01-06T11:35:19.579Z INFO wdio-local-runner: Run worker command: run

[0-0] 2019-01-06T11:35:19.749Z INFO webdriver: [POST] http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub/session

[0-0] 2019-01-06T11:35:19.749Z INFO webdriver: DATA { capabilities:

   { alwaysMatch: { browserName: 'chrome' }, firstMatch: [ {} ] },

  desiredCapabilities: { browserName: 'chrome' } }

[0-0] 2019-01-06T11:35:22.427Z INFO webdriver: COMMAND navigateTo("https://theculturetrip.com/europe/united-kingdom/england/london/before-you-go/")

[0-0] 2019-01-06T11:35:22.428Z INFO webdriver: [POST] http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub/session/d7e2b630ea4d1841e919ec800890b592/url

[0-0] 2019-01-06T11:35:22.428Z INFO webdriver: DATA { url:

   'https://theculturetrip.com/europe/united-kingdom/england/london/before-you-go/' }

[0-0] 2019-01-06T11:35:28.394Z INFO webdriver: COMMAND findElement("css selector", "[class*="LayoutWrapper"]")

[0-0] 2019-01-06T11:35:28.394Z INFO webdriver: [POST] http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub/session/d7e2b630ea4d1841e919ec800890b592/element

[0-0] 2019-01-06T11:35:28.394Z INFO webdriver: DATA { using: 'css selector', value: '[class*="LayoutWrapper"]' }

[0-0] 2019-01-06T11:35:28.417Z INFO webdriver: RESULT { ELEMENT: '0.5487788910074598-1' }

[0-0] 2019-01-06T11:35:28.439Z INFO webdriver: COMMAND isElementDisplayed("0.5487788910074598-1")

[0-0] 2019-01-06T11:35:28.439Z INFO webdriver: [GET] http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub/session/d7e2b630ea4d1841e919ec800890b592/element/0.5487788910074598-1/displayed

[0-0] 2019-01-06T11:35:28.455Z INFO webdriver: RESULT true

[0-0] 2019-01-06T11:35:28.456Z INFO webdriver: COMMAND findElement("css selector", "[class*="_Icon-"]")

[0-0] 2019-01-06T11:35:28.456Z INFO webdriver: [POST] http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub/session/d7e2b630ea4d1841e919ec800890b592/element

[0-0] 2019-01-06T11:35:28.456Z INFO webdriver: DATA { using: 'css selector', value: '[class*="_Icon-"]' }

[0-0] 2019-01-06T11:35:28.471Z INFO webdriver: RESULT { ELEMENT: '0.5487788910074598-2' }

[0-0] 2019-01-06T11:35:28.473Z INFO webdriver: COMMAND elementClick("0.5487788910074598-2")

[0-0] 2019-01-06T11:35:28.473Z INFO webdriver: COMMAND elementClick("0.5487788910074598-2")

[0-0] 2019-01-06T11:35:28.473Z INFO webdriver: [POST] http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub/session/d7e2b630ea4d1841e919ec800890b592/element/0.5487788910074598-2/click

[0-0] 2019-01-06T11:35:28.528Z INFO webdriver: COMMAND findElements("css selector", "[itemprop="item"]")

[0-0] 2019-01-06T11:35:28.528Z INFO webdriver: [POST] http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub/session/d7e2b630ea4d1841e919ec800890b592/elements

[0-0] 2019-01-06T11:35:28.528Z INFO webdriver: DATA { using: 'css selector', value: '[itemprop="item"]' }

[0-0] 2019-01-06T11:35:28.543Z INFO webdriver: RESULT [ { ELEMENT: '0.5487788910074598-3' },

  { ELEMENT: '0.5487788910074598-4' } ]

[0-0] 2019-01-06T11:35:28.556Z INFO webdriver: COMMAND deleteSession()

[0-0] 2019-01-06T11:35:28.556Z INFO webdriver: [DELETE] http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub/session/d7e2b630ea4d1841e919ec800890b592

2019-01-06T11:35:28.788Z DEBUG wdio-local-runner: Runner 0-0 finished with exit code 1



Test Suites:     0 passed, 1 failed, 1 total (100% completed)

Time:              13.05s



npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

Do you have an idea why?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think a different reporter could help you with that, check out spec reporter for instance https://webdriver.io/docs/spec-reporter.html

Comment: Hi, it did help with the expect result, now it does give an error message of: [chrome 71.0.3578.98 Windows NT #0-0] expected 2 to equal 3.
However, it still doesn't give an error in case the element wasn't found in the DOM...

Comment: what does it log in such an event ?

Comment: Well now for example, if I preform click on an element which is not displayed in DOM, I receive: " Timeout of 10000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves. "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**LE:** This is related to a issue ([BUG#2639](https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/issues/2639)) that will be fixed in WebdriverIO Version 5 (`webdriverio@5.x.x`), somewhere in the near future. This behavior affects all `sync: true` WDIO setups.

To conclude, here's the project lead maintainer's take on the matter:

> Just fyi: this will be fixed in v5 where the underlying monad
>   structure is more simplified and will actually work.
>
> If anyone is interested in a fix for this, feel free to propose a PR
>   on the v4 branch. This is most likely fixed in v5.

---

I think that is pretty much custom with the setup you're running, unless you add some fancy reporters for extra verbosity & display swag. Just visit the **Reporters** section from the [Official Guide](https://webdriver.io/docs/gettingstarted.html).

**Alternatives:**

**a.)** You can enhance verbosity at the assertion-level, using the optional `msg` param as so:

```
expect(breadcrumbsAppearancesNumber, `Found: ${breadcrumbsAppearancesNumber} breadcrumbs | Expected: 3 breadcrumbs`).to.equal(3);
```

**b.)** Or, increase the log verbosity (`logLevel: verbose`) in your `wdio.conf.js` file:

```
exports.config = {
  // ...
  //
  // Level of logging verbosity: silent | verbose | command | data | result | error
  logLevel: 'verbose',
  //
  // ... 
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! thing is that for example, if I preform click command on a selector which not appears in DOM, I would expect to receive an error which says something like "element ... was not found"... but what I actually receive is: " Timeout of 10000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves. "

Comment: No problem @DanielO! I updated the answer with the bleak resolution (*this is an unfixed issue affecting sync WDIO setups*). Cheers!

Comment: Ok now i've just updated to webdriver.io ver 5.2.4, and it seems to work - it prints in the Stdout: "'no such element: Unable to locate element:", as I was expected to receive. Thanks!!